# Querying SQLite Data to a TextView from a choice in a spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am querying my db to fill my spinner selections (this works fine) but I also want to populate some TextViews in the rest of the Activity from the selected position.
This is my class to handle the Activity:

```
public class Post_Player_Info extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
Spinner spinner;
TextView SportType;
Button Left, Right, Front, Back;
DBAdapter Info = new DBAdapter(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.postplayerinfo);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    SportType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSportType);

    db.open();

    Cursor c = db.getNames();

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        c,  new String[] {DBAdapter.ROW_FIRSTNAME}, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    db.close();

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch (position) {
    case 0: 
        Info.open();
        String data = Info.getData();
        SportType.setText(data);
        Info.close();
    break;

    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Here is where I am trying to get the data in my dbhelper:

```
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String [] {ROW_SPORT};
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String results = "";

    int sport = c.getColumnIndex(ROW_SPORT);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        results = results + c.getString(sport) + " ";
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure what the problem is... But this is my guess:

I don't see this line in onCreate():

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

---

Also please read about [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), which suggests that variables like `SportText` should start with a lowercase letter like `sportText`.

---

I noticed that you have both `db` and `Info`, but they do the same thing. You can remove one of these.

Comment: spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
this line fixed my issue. I can not thank you enough! I will look into the naming issues.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please select the checkmark in the upper left corner of this answer to mark this question as solved.